# Residence permit longer than visa duration?

Tags: germany

According to [this article](https://www.study-in-germany.de/en/germany/arrival/residence-permit/), one must apply for a resident permit after landing in Germany. So, normally it is given for one year. What if my visa lasts shorter than the residency permit? would I have to renew the visa too or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> would I have to renew the visa too?

No. The residence permit replaces your visa.  With a valid residence permit, you have no need for a visa.

Comment: So, let's say I am entering Germany, what do I show at border control?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom your foreign passport and your German residence permit.  You would show the same to board a flight to the Schengen area from a non-Schengen airport.